# How to prevent page refresh when <a> tag clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I need to pass a parameter into the URL and at the same time prevent page from reloading when I click any `<a>` tag with a blank `href` attribute (`<a href="">`)

Is there a way to do this with JS/jQuery?

I have this jQuery already

```
$('.list-group-item a').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But when I click `<a href="inbox/1">Message</a>` (any anchor with an href) preventDefault stops that value from being passed into the url.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to say? What exactly do you wanna do with the value?

Comment: I think he need to change the url without redirect

Comment: I need to change the URL without redirect as Shijin said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.hash="inbox/1"` can update the hash value in the url. This can be done with the event [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) code.

Comment: Thanks man. This actually did the trick. Now I am looking at getting the value after # (hash) with Jquery Ajax.

Comment: To get the value after hash -> window.location.hash

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
  $('.list-group-item a').click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Title",url); // this will change your url
 });
```

For More details http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to prevent click event in case of blank href like,

```
$('.list-group-item a[href=""]').click(function (event) { // where href are blank
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

And I would like to suggest don't make empty the `href's`, you can place `#` if no links are there.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [fancy selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), especially the [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/#post-47) one.

Using it, you can select only `<a>` tags which have a blank href attribute:

```
$('.list-group-item a[href=""]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

The `$('.list-group-item a[href=""]')` selector narrows the collected elements to only those anchor tags with a class of `list-group-item` and a blank href.

That means all other anchor tags will work fine.